# Pandas create new Dataframe where 2 minute data is aligned with 1 minute

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the same csv:

```
Time,o1,h1,l1,c1,o2,h2,l2,c2
        2019.04.08 23:59:00,1.12582,1.1261,1.12582,1.12609,1.12588,1.12591,1.12587,1.12588
        2019.04.09 00:00:00,1.12587,1.12598,1.12587,1.12598,1.12583,1.1261,1.12582,1.12609
        2019.04.09 00:01:00,1.12599,1.12607,1.12587,1.12607,1.12598,1.12607,1.12587,1.12607
        2019.04.09 00:02:00,1.12607,1.12632,1.12605,1.12632,1.12598,1.12607,1.12587,1.12607
        2019.04.09 00:03:00,1.12603,1.12614,1.12603,1.12613,1.12607,1.12632,1.12603,1.12613
        2019.04.09 00:04:00,1.12613,1.12613,1.12609,1.12611,1.12607,1.12632,1.12603,1.12613
        2019.04.09 00:05:00,1.12612,1.12613,1.12612,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12609,1.12613
        2019.04.09 00:06:00,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12609,1.12613
        2019.04.09 00:07:00,1.12613,1.12613,1.1261,1.12612,1.12613,1.12613,1.1261,1.12612
        2019.04.09 00:08:00,1.12612,1.12612,1.12612,1.12612,1.12613,1.12613,1.1261,1.12612
        2019.04.09 00:09:00,1.12612,1.12612,1.12609,1.12609,1.12612,1.12612,1.12609,1.12609
        2019.04.09 00:10:00,1.12609,1.12609,1.12602,1.12607,1.12612,1.12612,1.12609,1.12609
        2019.04.09 00:11:00,1.12607,1.12609,1.12607,1.12608,1.12609,1.12609,1.12602,1.12608
        2019.04.09 00:12:00,1.12608,1.12608,1.12608,1.12608,1.12609,1.12609,1.12602,1.12608
        2019.04.09 00:13:00,1.12608,1.12608,1.126,1.126,1.12608,1.12608,1.126,1.126
        2019.04.09 00:14:00,1.126,1.126,1.1259,1.12592,1.12608,1.12608,1.126,1.126
        2019.04.09 00:15:00,1.12592,1.12614,1.12592,1.12613,1.126,1.12614,1.1259,1.12613
        2019.04.09 00:16:00,1.12614,1.12619,1.12612,1.12619,1.126,1.12614,1.1259,1.12613
        2019.04.09 00:17:00,1.12619,1.1262,1.12615,1.12615,1.12614,1.1262,1.12612,1.12615
        2019.04.09 00:18:00,1.12616,1.12616,1.12608,1.12608,1.12614,1.1262,1.12612,1.12615
        2019.04.09 00:19:00,1.12608,1.12611,1.12608,1.12611,1.12616,1.12616,1.12608,1.12611
        2019.04.09 00:20:00,1.12608,1.12637,1.12608,1.1262,1.12616,1.12616,1.12608,1.12611
        2019.04.09 00:21:00,1.1262,1.12631,1.12614,1.12623,1.12608,1.12637,1.12608,1.12623
        2019.04.09 00:22:00,1.12624,1.12646,1.12619,1.12626,1.12608,1.12637,1.12608,1.12623
        2019.04.09 00:23:00,1.12626,1.12628,1.12585,1.1261,1.12624,1.12646,1.12585,1.1261
        2019.04.09 00:24:00,1.12609,1.12621,1.12607,1.12616,1.12624,1.12646,1.12585,1.1261
        2019.04.09 00:25:00,1.12615,1.12625,1.12609,1.1262,1.12609,1.12625,1.12607,1.1262
        2019.04.09 00:26:00,1.1262,1.12629,1.12615,1.12618,1.12609,1.12625,1.12607,1.1262
        2019.04.09 00:27:00,1.12618,1.12621,1.12614,1.12617,1.1262,1.12629,1.12614,1.12617
        2019.04.09 00:28:00,1.12618,1.12618,1.12586,1.12587,1.1262,1.12629,1.12614,1.12617
        2019.04.09 00:29:00,1.12586,1.12598,1.12586,1.12597,1.12618,1.12618,1.12586,1.12597
        2019.04.09 00:30:00,1.12598,1.12608,1.12594,1.12604,1.12618,1.12618,1.12586,1.12597
```

I want to know how in Pandas Dataframe I can do this:

```
Time,o1,h1,l1,c1,o2,h2,l2,c2,o11,h11,l11,c11
2019.04.08 23:59:00,1.12582,1.1261,1.12582,1.12609,1.12588,1.12591,1.12587,1.12588,1.12587,1.12598,1.12587,1.12598
2019.04.09 00:01:00,1.12599,1.12607,1.12587,1.12607,1.12598,1.12607,1.12587,1.12607,1.12607,1.12632,1.12605,1.12632
2019.04.09 00:03:00,1.12603,1.12614,1.12603,1.12613,1.12607,1.12632,1.12603,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12609,1.12611
2019.04.09 00:05:00,1.12612,1.12613,1.12612,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12609,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613,1.12613
2019.04.09 00:07:00,1.12613,1.12613,1.1261,1.12612,1.12613,1.12613,1.1261,1.12612,1.12612,1.12612,1.12612,1.12612
2019.04.09 00:09:00,1.12612,1.12612,1.12609,1.12609,1.12612,1.12612,1.12609,1.12609,1.12609,1.12609,1.12602,1.12607
```

I want to append the data of 2 minutes to 1 minute as shown in the above example.
Kindly let me know.

Comment: What is your method of appending?

Comment: Thinking to create a new column and write data in that. But don't know whether it is feasible with python pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions of column from list and fiter rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together:

```
pos2 = df.columns.get_indexer(['o1','h1','l1','c1'])
df1 = df.iloc[0::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df.iloc[1::2, pos2].reset_index(drop=True)

df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='1')
```

---

```
print (df)

                   Time       o1       h1       l1       c1       o2       h2  \
0   2019.04.08 23:59:00  1.12582  1.12610  1.12582  1.12609  1.12588  1.12591   
1   2019.04.09 00:01:00  1.12599  1.12607  1.12587  1.12607  1.12598  1.12607   
2   2019.04.09 00:03:00  1.12603  1.12614  1.12603  1.12613  1.12607  1.12632   
3   2019.04.09 00:05:00  1.12612  1.12613  1.12612  1.12613  1.12613  1.12613   
4   2019.04.09 00:07:00  1.12613  1.12613  1.12610  1.12612  1.12613  1.12613   
5   2019.04.09 00:09:00  1.12612  1.12612  1.12609  1.12609  1.12612  1.12612   
6   2019.04.09 00:11:00  1.12607  1.12609  1.12607  1.12608  1.12609  1.12609   
7   2019.04.09 00:13:00  1.12608  1.12608  1.12600  1.12600  1.12608  1.12608   
8   2019.04.09 00:15:00  1.12592  1.12614  1.12592  1.12613  1.12600  1.12614   
9   2019.04.09 00:17:00  1.12619  1.12620  1.12615  1.12615  1.12614  1.12620   
10  2019.04.09 00:19:00  1.12608  1.12611  1.12608  1.12611  1.12616  1.12616   
11  2019.04.09 00:21:00  1.12620  1.12631  1.12614  1.12623  1.12608  1.12637   
12  2019.04.09 00:23:00  1.12626  1.12628  1.12585  1.12610  1.12624  1.12646   
13  2019.04.09 00:25:00  1.12615  1.12625  1.12609  1.12620  1.12609  1.12625   
14  2019.04.09 00:27:00  1.12618  1.12621  1.12614  1.12617  1.12620  1.12629   
15  2019.04.09 00:29:00  1.12586  1.12598  1.12586  1.12597  1.12618  1.12618   

         l2       c2      o11      h11      l11      c11  
0   1.12587  1.12588  1.12587  1.12598  1.12587  1.12598  
1   1.12587  1.12607  1.12607  1.12632  1.12605  1.12632  
2   1.12603  1.12613  1.12613  1.12613  1.12609  1.12611  
3   1.12609  1.12613  1.12613  1.12613  1.12613  1.12613  
4   1.12610  1.12612  1.12612  1.12612  1.12612  1.12612  
5   1.12609  1.12609  1.12609  1.12609  1.12602  1.12607  
6   1.12602  1.12608  1.12608  1.12608  1.12608  1.12608  
7   1.12600  1.12600  1.12600  1.12600  1.12590  1.12592  
8   1.12590  1.12613  1.12614  1.12619  1.12612  1.12619  
9   1.12612  1.12615  1.12616  1.12616  1.12608  1.12608  
10  1.12608  1.12611  1.12608  1.12637  1.12608  1.12620  
11  1.12608  1.12623  1.12624  1.12646  1.12619  1.12626  
12  1.12585  1.12610  1.12609  1.12621  1.12607  1.12616  
13  1.12607  1.12620  1.12620  1.12629  1.12615  1.12618  
14  1.12614  1.12617  1.12618  1.12618  1.12586  1.12587  
15  1.12586  1.12597  1.12598  1.12608  1.12594  1.12604
```

EDIT: For add missing rows for one minute frequency by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
print (df)
                  Time       o1       h1       l1       c1       o2       h2  \
0  2019.04.10 16:16:00  1.12308  1.12340  1.12304  1.12327  1.12350  1.12369   
1  2019.04.10 16:17:00  1.12327  1.12333  1.12302  1.12322  1.12308  1.12340   
2  2019.04.10 16:21:00  1.12314  1.12354  1.12313  1.12353  1.12314  1.12354   
3  2019.04.10 16:22:00  1.12353  1.12362  1.12345  1.12359  1.12314  1.12354   
4  2019.04.10 16:23:00  1.12359  1.12389  1.12357  1.12383  1.12353  1.12389   
5  2019.04.10 16:24:00  1.12383  1.12396  1.12375  1.12384  1.12353  1.12389   
6  2019.04.10 16:25:00  1.12383  1.12389  1.12373  1.12376  1.12383  1.12396   
7  2019.04.10 16:26:00  1.12376  1.12386  1.12355  1.12361  1.12383  1.12396   

        l2       c2  
0  1.12300  1.12308  
1  1.12302  1.12322  
2  1.12313  1.12353  
3  1.12313  1.12353  
4  1.12345  1.12383  
5  1.12345  1.12383  
6  1.12373  1.12376  
7  1.12373  1.12376
```

---

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('1min').reset_index()
#if need forward filling missing values
#df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('1min', method='ffill').reset_index()
print (df)
                  Time       o1       h1       l1       c1       o2       h2  \
0  2019-04-10 16:16:00  1.12308  1.12340  1.12304  1.12327  1.12350  1.12369   
1  2019-04-10 16:17:00  1.12327  1.12333  1.12302  1.12322  1.12308  1.12340   
2  2019-04-10 16:18:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
3  2019-04-10 16:19:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
4  2019-04-10 16:20:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
5  2019-04-10 16:21:00  1.12314  1.12354  1.12313  1.12353  1.12314  1.12354   
6  2019-04-10 16:22:00  1.12353  1.12362  1.12345  1.12359  1.12314  1.12354   
7  2019-04-10 16:23:00  1.12359  1.12389  1.12357  1.12383  1.12353  1.12389   
8  2019-04-10 16:24:00  1.12383  1.12396  1.12375  1.12384  1.12353  1.12389   
9  2019-04-10 16:25:00  1.12383  1.12389  1.12373  1.12376  1.12383  1.12396   
10 2019-04-10 16:26:00  1.12376  1.12386  1.12355  1.12361  1.12383  1.12396   

         l2       c2  
0   1.12300  1.12308  
1   1.12302  1.12322  
2       NaN      NaN  
3       NaN      NaN  
4       NaN      NaN  
5   1.12313  1.12353  
6   1.12313  1.12353  
7   1.12345  1.12383  
8   1.12345  1.12383  
9   1.12373  1.12376  
10  1.12373  1.12376
```

---

```
pos2 = df.columns.get_indexer(['o1','h1','l1','c1'])
df1 = df.iloc[0::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df.iloc[1::2, pos2].reset_index(drop=True)

df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='1')
print (df)
                 Time       o1       h1       l1       c1       o2       h2  \
0 2019-04-10 16:16:00  1.12308  1.12340  1.12304  1.12327  1.12350  1.12369   
1 2019-04-10 16:18:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2 2019-04-10 16:20:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
3 2019-04-10 16:22:00  1.12353  1.12362  1.12345  1.12359  1.12314  1.12354   
4 2019-04-10 16:24:00  1.12383  1.12396  1.12375  1.12384  1.12353  1.12389   
5 2019-04-10 16:26:00  1.12376  1.12386  1.12355  1.12361  1.12383  1.12396   

        l2       c2      o11      h11      l11      c11  
0  1.12300  1.12308  1.12327  1.12333  1.12302  1.12322  
1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
2      NaN      NaN  1.12314  1.12354  1.12313  1.12353  
3  1.12313  1.12353  1.12359  1.12389  1.12357  1.12383  
4  1.12345  1.12383  1.12383  1.12389  1.12373  1.12376  
5  1.12373  1.12376      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: But I also want to have the data from `o2,h2,l2,c2`.

Comment: @JafferWilson - sorry, I miss it, answer was changed for all columns for `df1`

Comment: It is possible to check the time minute divisibility because it may happen that dataset  miss entries. So i I can get to know how to check the 2 minute and append to the first minute that it would be a better solution.

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson - Use `df = df. set_index('Time'). asfreq('1min'). reset_index()` first

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson I am on phone only, so not easy testing now.

Comment: I can understand. Just for information I have got this sort of missed entries and hence, the above solution might not be helpful in my case: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/b04e7142f74841d7efba6321858a6828

Comment: @JafferWilson - Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you I guess this will help.

Answer (score 0):

split data then join:

```
# split data every other row
n = df[0::2]
n1 = df[1::2]

# reset_index and join
new_df = n.reset_index(drop=True).join(n1.reset_index(drop=True), rsuffix='_other')
```

Then drop the columns you do not want